# Kubernetes cluster has oplock (samba) on file in Azure storage account

Tags: azure, samba, cifs

I'm running the [bradbeck/nexus-https](https://github.com/bradbeck/nexus-https) container using kubernetes in Azure Container Service and mounting the `/nexus-data` volume against an Azure storage account File Share. On the k8s-agents I installed `cifs-utils` to access the file share.

When the pod exited, perhaps not gracefully(?), the samba client put the `pending delete` flag on `/nexus-data/cache/cache.lock` and has not released it.

When I try to start a new pod mounting the same file share, it fails with:

> File does not exist: /nexus-data/cache/cache.lock

When I try to delete it through the Azure Portal, it fails with:

> Failed to delete file 'nexus-data/cache/cache.lock'. Error: The specified resource is marked for deletion by an SMB client.

That is a [409 error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/managing-file-locks#smb-delete-implications-on-rest).

**How do I break this lock / get rid of this file?**

---

*Edit:* I tried restarting the k8s-agents, but even this didn't work! Fortunately I could delete the entire file share, and recreate it. That might not by an option in the future: `az storage share delete --name nexus-data`

Comment: My only solution so far is to delete the deployment and wait for the lock to expire. I'm not sure how long that takes?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26171306/297331

Comment: Seems like locks don't always expire

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Nexus per se. I experienced the same thing with a TeamCity server as well.

What is happening is that when a container dies the samba file share is not unmounted on the host machine. I haven't yet figured out how to work out which entry in `/etc/mtab` belongs to the data volume of the dead container. For now I'm restarting the host, which unmounts the file system and allows the delete instruction to complete.